# How I proceed with awk after if statement

Tags: awk

my input:

```
Jun 26 06:54:33 host dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<xxx>, method=PLAIN, rip=111.111.111.111, lip=111.111.111.111, mpid=00000, TLS, session=<LVVIgfWodFBZD+3W>
```

Like to get the IP of the rip entry with one command

```
awk '{ if ($6 == "imap-login:" && match($10,/rip/) ) { print $10 }  }'
```

give me "rip=78.47.14.44,"

How it works to get only the IP?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/rip[^,]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4)}' Input_file
```

OR as per kvantour sir's suggestion:

```
awk 'match($0,/[:,] rip[^,]*/){val=substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4);sub(/.*rip/,"");print val;val=""}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                      ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/rip[^,]*/){                      ##Using match to match regex of rip till comma comes in current line,if regex match is found then it sets variables RSTART and RLENGTH for match.
  print substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-4)      ##Printing sub string from RSTART+4 value to RLENGTH+4 values to get exact IP which is coming with strig rip in line.
}
' Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: More robust would be `/[:,] rip[^,]*/` this will pick `rip` even if it is at the beginning of the list and will avoid matches such as `rrip`

Comment: @kvantour, Sure, thanks for suggestion I have added solution too now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[ =,]+' '$6=="imap-login:"{print $13}' file
111.111.111.111
```